# How to select from table where text box = formula with aggregates (Xojo+ SQLite)

Tags: sqlite, formula, aggregates, xojo

I have a table with columns;

- Fullname,
- GroupNo,
- Tdate,
- Schedule,
- Cramount,
- Dramount,
- Iamount.

I want to select those columns where textbox111.text is greater than formula `SUM(Cramount)*26/(SUM(Dramount+Iamount))`.

The SQL below give me syntax error, can someone help me please DATABASE IS SQLITE AND PROGRAMMING IN XOJO.

```
 sql= "SELECT Fullname, GroupNo, Tdate, Schedule,( SUM(Cramount)*26)/SUM(Dramount+Iamount) AS ok FROM Trans WHERE Branchcode = '1210 - Loans'GROUP BY LoanID  HAVING SUM(Cramount)*26/(SUM(Dramount+Iamount)) < '"TextBox111.text'""
```

Comment: tidy up formatting

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things wrong with your SQL string, you've got the single and double quote after the TextBox111.text around the wrong way, and you need to concatenate that control value with "+" as Xojo does not do string interpolation.

Try something like:

```
sql= "SELECT Fullname, GroupNo, Tdate, Schedule, (SUM(Cramount)*26)/SUM(Dramount+Iamount) AS ok FROM Trans WHERE Branchcode = '1210 - Loans' GROUP BY LoanID HAVING SUM(Cramount)*26/(SUM(Dramount+Iamount)) < '" + TextBox111.text + "'"
```

I'm pretty sure that SQLite supports using the alias for the agregate field in the having clause...

```
sql= "SELECT Fullname, GroupNo, Tdate, Schedule, (SUM(Cramount)*26)/SUM(Dramount+Iamount) AS ok FROM Trans WHERE Branchcode = '1210 - Loans' GROUP BY LoanID HAVING ok < '" + TextBox111.text + "'"
```

Your SQL also references two fields that you don't mention in as being in your table, Branchcode and LoanID, hopefully you just forgot to mention them.